# ImportPage with itextsharp doesn't work as expected

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, version

I have a process to insert a PDF page from an existing PDF into another PDF that is created from scratch using `PdfWriter` in a web application (the new PDF is created as a content response sent to a browser).

This works fine until today, but now I've hit a problem.

I use itextsharp and the `GetImportedPage`. I try to update my itextsharp dll but still not working, I only get a blank page in my pdf.

Comment: Please provide the PDFs in question and your pivotal code.

Comment: here a project test with my problem
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6EF086014F5F1E58!124&authkey=!AMHIdbYnHuznAxw&ithint=file%2c.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following screen shot:
[image]

As you can see, the page dictionary has a `/Rotate` entry with value 90.

Now look at your code:

```
if ((ReceiptPageRotation == 90) || (ReceiptPageRotation == 270)) {
    writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(importedPage, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f, 0, ReceiptReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height);
}
else {
    writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
}
```

If the page has no rotation, you position the imported page at the lower-left coordinate of an A4 page. This will work if your original page is also an A4 page. If the original page has a different format, your new page may be too big or too small.

However, it the page is rotated, *as is the case with test.pdf*, you perform a really strange transformation and translation.
You *are* adding the page (you'll notice this when you look at the file size of the resulting file), but you're completely deforming the original page and you're adding it outside of the visible area of the page.

Please throw away your code and start anew. You should read [Chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) and consider using `PdfStamper` instead of `PdfWriter`.